# My DataTables within this method are producing csv files that are double the number of rows they contain, why?

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, filtering

I have the below method, im trying to clean up a text file based on some criteria, with everyones help ive already gotten this far and everything is working and creating and filtering, BUT something i noticed during my last set of tests is that the number of rows expected in the csv files im generating(only for testing purposes) are double the size of the actual datatable, so the first datatable in my method is called "output" which the row count is 2257, but the csv that is created has 4514 records in it and the 2nd csv called outputLoc row count is 1402 but the csv file ends up with 2804 records..

Here is the code currently being executed and working, but generating the above numbers.

```
try
{
    DataTable d = processFileData(concatFile);

    // REMOVES ALL RECORDS WITH A CLASS THAT IS NON-LABEL CLASS                    
    var query = from r in d.AsEnumerable()
                where !returnClass().Any(r.Field<string>("Column7").Contains)
                select r;

    DataTable output = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>(); // Should have 2257 records
    int dtoutputCount = output.Rows.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < dtoutputCount; i++)
    {
        DataRow rows = output.Rows[i];
        output.ImportRow(rows);
    }

    ToCSV(output, ftype,"filteredclass");  // Only writing to csv for testing and verification of data

    //// REMOVES ALL RECORDS THAT HAVE A NON-SELLING OR UNOPENED LOCATION
    var queryLoc = from rL in output.AsEnumerable()
                   where !returnLocations().Any(rL.Field<string>("Column2").Contains)
                   select rL;

    DataTable outputLoc = queryLoc.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
    int dtoutputLocCount = outputLoc.Rows.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < dtoutputLocCount; i++)
    {
        DataRow rows = outputLoc.Rows[i];
        outputLoc.ImportRow(rows);
    }

    ToCSV(outputLoc, ftype,"filteredlocation");  // Only writing to csv for testing and verification of data

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException);
}
```

Once everything is working as expect, we would eventually get rid of the ToCSV calls so that we can work with the data in memory and once its all cleaned, then we call that to produce the final file that has been filtered down.

Any help would be greatly appreciated in determining why im getting a file that is exactly twice as big as expected.

Comment: You are executing a loop with a call to ImportRow on the same table where you are reading the rows. This doubles the rows in the table

Comment: So do i even need this section?                int dtoutputCount = output.Rows.Count;

                for (int i = 0; i < dtoutputCount; i++)
                {
                    DataRow rows = output.Rows[i];
                    output.ImportRow(rows);
                }

Comment: No absolutely no. The previous _CopyToDataTable<DataRow>_  has already filled the table with the records

Comment: wow, ok, i just commented that out and def reduced the size of the first file correctly(still need to verify) but it reduced the 2nd file alot more than expected, so ill have to research that one and see what if anything is going on there.. thank you for the help

Comment: So checked the files this morning and not seeing the correct values in the last file. The 2 files that get created should have the following total of records in them. The filtered class file should have 2257 records and it does. The filtered location file should have 1402 records and it only has 701 records. The count of rows for this line DataTable outputLoc = queryLoc.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>(); is 1402. I then instantly call this line ToCSV(outputLoc, ftype,"filteredlocation");  the file created is only 701 records.. what just happened between getting the count and the creation of the file?

Comment: No idea, unless the ToCSV has somenthing to do with that.